# Best way to null check in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Should I use double `=`, or triple `=`?

```
if(a === null)  {
//do something
}
```

or

```
if(a == null)  {
//do something
}
```

Similarly for 'not equals':

```
if(a !== null)  {
//do something
}
```

or

```
if(a != null)  {
//do something
}
```

Comment: have look on link :- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html                        .............. It easy in Kotlin Docs

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Both approaches generate the same bytecode so you can choose whatever you prefer.

Comment: If i understood it correctly then he is asking for best way to check  null in Kotlin, not which approach generates best byte-code.@BenitoBertoli answer looks promising, it's reduces boilerplate code

Answer (score 249):

A structural equality `a == b` is translated to

```
a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)
```

Therefore when comparing to `null`, the structural equality `a == null` is translated to a referential equality `a === null`.

According to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html), there is no point in optimizing your code, so you can use `a == null` and `a != null`

**Note** that if the variable is a mutable property, you won't be able to smart cast it to its non-nullable type inside the `if` statement (because the value might have been modified by another thread) and you'd have to use the safe call operator with `let` instead.

**Safe call operator** `?.`

```
a?.let {
   // not null do something
   println(it)
   println("not null")
}
```

You can use it in combination with the Elvis operator.

**Elvis operator `?:`** *(I'm guessing because the interrogation mark looks like Elvis' hair)*

```
a ?: println("null")
```

And if you want to run a block of code

```
a ?: run {
    println("null")
    println("The King has left the building")
}
```

**Combining the two**

```
a?.let {
   println("not null")
   println("Wop-bop-a-loom-a-boom-bam-boom")
} ?: run {
    println("null")
    println("When things go null, don't go with them")
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `if` for null checks? `a?.let{} ?: run{}` is only appropriate in rare cases, otherwise it is not idiomatic

Comment: @voddan I wasn't suggesting not using if for `null` checks, I was listing other viable options. Although I'm not sure if `run` has some kind of performance penalty. I'll update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @voddan If `a` is a `var`, then using the `a?.let{} ?: run{}` guarantee that it will be bound properly in the `let` for the whole scope. If `a` is a `val`, then there is no difference.

Comment: @madeinqc if a is a `val`, then using let is different and it's bad. I found this article very good at explaining it - [Kotlin: Don’t just use LET for null check](https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-dont-just-use-let-7e91f544e27f).

Comment: @voddan I'm new to Kotlin. Would you please explain or provide a URL noting how this is not idiomatic?

Comment: Let will not work for `var ar = ArrayList<*>? = null; (ar as? ArrayList<Type>).let` check `it` for null

Comment: @Qamar you have an unchecked cast. If you are sure about the type you can add @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") , and it will work.

Comment: @BenitoBertoli In the above statement, it will be null after let. I have to check if (it != null)

Answer (score 96):

### Kotlin ways of handling null

**Secure Access Operation**

```
val dialog: Dialog? = Dialog()
dialog?.dismiss()  // If the dialog is null, the dismiss call will be omitted
```

**Let function**

```
user?.let {
  // Work with non-null user
  handleNonNullUser(user)
}
```

**Early exit**

```
fun handleUser(user: User?) {
  user ?: return // Exit the function if user is null
  // Now the compiler knows user is non-null
}
```

**Immutable shadows**

```
var user: User? = null

fun handleUser() {
  val user = user ?: return // Return if null, otherwise create immutable shadow
  // Work with a local non-null variable named user
}
```

**Default value**

```
fun getUserName(): String {
 // If our nullable reference is not null, use it, otherwise use non-null value 
 return userName ?: "Anonymous"
}
```

**Use val instead of var**

`val` is read-only, `var` is mutable. It's recommended to use as many read-only properties as you can, they are thread-safe.

**Use lateinit**

Sometimes you can't use immutable properties. For example, it happens on Android when some property is initialized in `onCreate()` call. For these situations, Kotlin has a language feature called `lateinit`.

```
private lateinit var mAdapter: RecyclerAdapter<Transaction>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   mAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(R.layout.item_transaction)
}

fun updateTransactions() {
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: I'd call the last one "default value" (not elvis), since 3/4 of those are using elvis.

Comment: @AjahnCharles makes sense ))

Comment: this is garbage, any language modern can deal better with optionals than this. its more a chore than a benefit for programmers.

Answer (score 19):

Addition to @Benito Bertoli,

the combination is actually unlike if-else

```
"test" ?. let {
    println ( "1. it=$it" )
} ?: let {
    println ( "2. it is null!" )
}
```

The result is:

```
1. it=test
```

But if:

```
"test" ?. let {
    println ( "1. it=$it" )
    null // finally returns null
} ?: let {
    println ( "2. it is null!" )
}
```

The result is:

```
1. it=test
2. it is null!
```

Also, if use elvis first:

```
null ?: let {
    println ( "1. it is null!" )
} ?. let {
    println ( "2. it=$it" )
}
```

The result is:

```
1. it is null!
2. it=kotlin.Unit
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile on  `1.7.20`. `let` is an extension function and you are using it as normal function in first 2 cases.

Answer (score 6):

Check useful methods out, it could be useful:

```
/**
 * Performs [R] when [T] is not null. Block [R] will have context of [T]
 */
inline fun <T : Any, R> ifNotNull(input: T?, callback: (T) -> R): R? {
    return input?.let(callback)
}

/**
 * Checking if [T] is not `null` and if its function completes or satisfies to some condition.
 */
inline fun <T: Any> T?.isNotNullAndSatisfies(check: T.() -> Boolean?): Boolean{
    return ifNotNull(this) { it.run(check) } ?: false
}
```

Below is possible example how to use those functions:

```
var s: String? = null

// ...

if (s.isNotNullAndSatisfies{ isEmpty() }{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to respond to answers of @Benito Bertoli and @BingLi224 and provide imho correct solution.

Problem is with using `let`, because result of `let` is it's last expression. You just want to pass the same thing as is passed into it, so `also` is a better solution. At the same time, after using elvis operator, `let` is impossible to use, because there is no object to call extension function to so I am using `run` (functional version). More on that in the [scope functions official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html)

Another downside of this compared to using `if`/`when` is not being able to use this as an expression so I  wouldn't recommend using it :-)

Final code:

```
"test"?.also {
    println("1. it=$it")
} ?: run {
    println("2. it is null!")
}

"test"?.also {
    println("1. it=$it")
    null
} ?: run {
    println("2. it is null!")
}

null?.also {
    println("1. it is null!")
} ?: run {
    println("2. it is null")
}

null?.also {
    println("1. it is null!")
    null
} ?: run {
    println("2. it is null")
}
```

And output:

```
1. it=test
1. it=test
2. it is null
2. it is null
```