# Stopping an app from crashing by checking if EditText is empty

Tags: android, kotlin

So i made a Calculator with 2 EditText inputs, but i couldn't stop the app from crashing when the 2 fields are empty. I found some solutions for EditText of Text type but am stuck here because i am using a Number EditText.
Here is the code by the way:
 {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
fun buPlusClick(view: View){

    var num1:Int=ednum1.text.toString().toInt()
    var num2:Int=ednum2.text.toString().toInt()
    var result = num1+num2
    val resultprint = "The result Is : $result"
    tvresult.text=resultprint
}
```

}

Comment: Add validation before typecasting that your ednum1 and ednum2 is not empty.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: the four calculation methods are essentially identical so you only need one in the question. and it would help others if you include details of the crash

Comment: that's probably why you've been downvoted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're likely getting is a NumberFormatException. This is because ("" != [0-9]+) && value value !< Int.MAX_VALUE && !> Int.MIN_VALUE.

You have three options:

1. Check if it's empty first, as sandip mentioned.
2. Use `toIntOrNull`
3. Catch the exception.

`toInt` throws an exception (NumberFormatException) if the int is invalid. This means:

1. Not a number with the defined radix (default 10; an actual int. I.e. 16 is hex, but it's not applicable here)
2. The number is too big or too small (under Int.MIN_VALUE or over Int.MAX_VALUE).
3. The String is empty.

Checking if it's empty first solves half the problem; it can't be valid if it's empty. However, it doesn't solve it if there are letters or the number is too big.

You can use `toIntOrNull()` for this. It's just like `toInt()`, but it returns null if the conversion fails. You can use the elvis operator with a run block, or just use a simple if-statement to check if it's null, and handle the problems accordingly.

```
val num1: Int = ednum1.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: run {
    // Notify the user the first number is invalid
    return; // return from the method to avoid NPE's
}
val num2: Int = ednum2.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: run {
    // Notify the user the second number is invalid
    return;
}
```

if you don't understand what `run` does here, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52539150/6296561). You can also get rid of `run` entirely and assign a number value, just let it be null and handle it later, or something else.

The max positive value of an int is about 2.4 billion. If you expect numbers with a higher input than that, use `Long`, and equivalently `toLongOrNull()`.

---

The last option is catching the error.

```
var num1: Int? = try { ednum1.text.toString().toInt() } catch (e: NumberFormatException) { 
    // You can do a lot of stuff in here; you can notify the user and `return` from the method,
    // set it to null and handle it later, or assign an integer value. 
    null 
}
var num2: Int? = try { ednum2.text.toString().toInt() } catch (e: NumberFormatException) { 
    // see my comments on the first block; same applies here
    null 
}
```

It is, in my opinion, slightly more bulky than `toIntOrNull()`( / `toLongOrNull()`), but it is an option.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check first editText empty or not.

```
//Java
private boolean isEmpty(EditText editText) {

if (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) 
    return false;

return true;

}

//kotlin
private fun isEmpty(editText: EditText): Boolean {

    return if (editText.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }.length > 0) false else true

}
```

Then do the following Code:

```
fun buPlusClick(view: View){

if(!isEmpty(ednum1) && !isEmpty(ednum2)) {

   var num1:Int=ednum1.text.toString().toInt()
   var num2:Int=ednum2.text.toString().toInt()
   var result = num1+num2
   val resultprint = "The result Is : $result"
   tvresult.text=resultprint
 }
}
```

Do the above check all of your functions.